# std::wstring not working with the [] operator of std::map<const wchar_t*, const char*>

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, std

I have a `const std::map<const wchar_t*, const char*>` which is in the global namespace. It looks like this:

**.h file**

```
typedef std::map<const wchar_t*, const char*> ShaderMap;

const ShaderMap::value_type rawShaderData[] = {
    ShaderMap::value_type( L"BasicShader_Vertex", 
        "..."
    ),
);

const int ElementCount = 2; //Length of rawShaderData
extern ShaderMap ShaderProgramsMap;
```

**.cpp file**

```
ShaderMap ShaderProgramsMap = ShaderMap( rawShaderData, rawShaderData + ElementCount );
```

I'm trying to access it elsewhere in my code like this:

```
std::wstring shaderKey = std::wstring( name + L"_Vertex" );
...
pShaderData = ShaderProgramsMap[shaderKey.c_str()];
```

Using the debugger, `shaderKey` is "BasicShader_vertex" but `pShaderData` is NULL. Is the problem with comparing the value of `std::wstring::c_str` to `const wchar_t*` or is it something elsewhere in the code?

Comment: Any reason to use std::map<const w_char_t*, const char*> instead of std::map<std::wstring, std::string> ?

Comment: Oh, and what'a the type of name?

Answer (score 5):

```
std::wstring shaderKey1 = std::wstring( name + L"_Vertex" );
ShaderProgramsMap[shaderKey1.c_str()] = "Whatever";

std::wstring shaderKey2 = std::wstring( name + L"_Vertex" );
pShaderData = ShaderProgramsMap[shaderKey2.c_str()];
```

The pointer returned by `shaderKey1.c_str()` is not the same as `shaderKey2.c_str()`. They are 2 different strings which both allocated their own data and are giving you a pointer to that allocation. They happen to store the same data, but you are only looking at the pointers. If you want to search and sort by string make the key a `std::wstring`, not a `const wchar_t*`. Along the same lines, the value should also very likely be `std::string`, not `const char*`, but I'll leave you to decide that.

Another problem with your original approach is that the pointer returned by `shaderKey.c_str()` will be dangling as soon as `shaderKey` goes out of scope.

Comment: Or keep the `map<wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*>`, use a custom comparator (that uses e.g. `strcmp`) and prepare for UB because of dangling pointers.

Comment: @Dyp: If the map is initialized using string literals, as the question suggests, then the pointers won't dangle.

Comment: @BenVoigt True, I meant it in the spirit of "if **all** map keys **always** point to objects of static storage duration" -> error-prone

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually see a std::map in your example code -- I see an array of std::map<>::**value_type** elements (i.e. const char*).

So,
   `const ShaderMap::value_type ShaderProgramsMap[] = { ... };`

is actually:
    `std::pair<wchar_t const* const, char const*> const ShaderProgramsMap[] = { ... }`

And,
    `pShaderData = ShaderProgramsMap[shaderKey.c_str()];`

is actually:

```
int nArrayIndex = int(shaderKey.c_str());
pShaderData = ShaderProgramsMap[nArrayIndex]; // actually an array, not a map
```

Comment: You make a good point about the code in the question... but the problem you point out should be causing a compile error -- there's no implicit conversion from `const char*` to int.

Comment: True -- Dave's answer is probably what the actual problem is, then

Comment: I actually copied the wrong code, and didn't notice when I posted! Sorry about that, I updated it with the proper code.